# Nested-form-field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have used Ryan Bates railscast tutorial to make this. But I'm running into a problem, I have tried to follow his example to the T but no luck.

The first part is giving my Projects table access to the questionnaires attributes.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :pid, :name, :qheader, :questionaires_attributes
 has_many :questionaires
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :questionaires, allow_destroy: true

 pid_regex = /\d+/

 validates :pid, presence: true, format: { with: pid_regex}, uniqueness: true
 validates :name, presence: true
 # validates :qheader, presence: true

end
```

I do the same thing for my Questionaire model, Please disregard the fact that questionnaire is misspelled for I have checked it everywhere to make sure it is spelled the same way.

```
class Questionaire < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :content, :project_id
 belongs_to :project
end
```

Then I built the new.html.erb for the view/projects

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_msgs' %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :pid %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :pid %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>
 <%= f.fields_for :questionaires do |builder| %>
   <%= render "questions", f: builder %>
 <% end %>

 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Add New Project" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

According to Ryan Bates, and it works from what I see,

```
 <%= f.fields_for :questionaires do |builder| %>
```

should be plural but when it is plural the fieldset, which is located in the rendered partial disappeared but it reappears when :questionaires is singular. but if I submit it, it tells me that it can't mass-assign to protected attribute :questionaires.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this.

Comment: I have found what it wrong with it. Just bad naming on my part. The partial should have been named questionaire_fields and it was missing a button to add a new questionaire field. It is working now. Including validations